# rails create labels without changing format(capitalization) from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formatting

I think this should be a pretty simple question, though I can't seem to find anything on it.

I have a form which includes a bunch of fields that are dynamically generated from a list in the Database (using fields_for).

The labels for each field look like this in database: ABC, DooRs, GREen DogS, aBc, etc.

My problem is that the label helper formats the label by simply capitalizing the first word of each field: Abc, Doors, Green dogs, Abc, etc.

Is there a way that I can keep the format from the Database?

**Code:**

```
<%= f.fields_for :dynamic do |s|  %>
<% s.label dyn.field_name %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply as:

```
<%= s.label dyn.field_name, dyn.field_name %>
```

and `field_name` will be preserved. The second argument actually defines label text and you can do any fancy operations on it:

```
<%= s.label dyn.field_name, "DB field: #{dyn.field_name}" %>
<%= s.label dyn.field_name, dyn.field_name.upcase %>
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about that.